# why is $(0,1) \subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

why is $(0,1) \subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{N}$

Sorry it seems very simple but  can't get my mind to understand why, I feel like 
 $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{N}$ = {all negative numbers and irrational numbers }

doesn't the $\subseteq$ mean that all elements in one set is contained in the other?

please help, thanks.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ means natural number, rational is usually denoted by $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ is the natural numbers, not the rational numbers. That is, $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$.

Comment: @NoahOlander You have a weird definition for $\Bbb N$. Everyone knows $\Bbb N = \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. :P

Comment: You mean $\{ 0 ,1 \}$, the set of $0$ and $1$? If this is the case, then the claim is false; for $\{ 1 \} \subset \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Please, zero is the natural-est number!

Comment: @Cameron: Nah, Noah has the natural definition of the natural numbers!

Comment: @CameronWilliams Both are used in different parts of the world.  Most German and American texts I know of use $\mathbb{N}$ to be the *non-negative* integers, but I have seen some people to mean the *strictly positive* integers, and in either definition, the inclusion in the question by the OP is true.

Comment: @JMoravitz: It’s worse than that: both are used in the *same* parts of the world!

Comment: @JMoravitz I was just making a really dry joke. It's a fun harmless argument to have.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the fast responses and great answers and discussion!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, $A\subseteq B$ means that each element of $A$ is also an element of $B$. And that is true if $A=(0,1)$ and $B=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb N$. First, it should be clear that every $x\in(0,1)$ is a real number, so $(0,1)\subseteq\Bbb R$. Does $(0,1)$ contain any natural number? No: it contains only the numbers strictly between $0$ and $1$, which don’t even include any integers, let alone natural numbers. Thus, $x\notin\Bbb N$ whenever $x\in(0,1)$. Put the pieces together: if $x\in(0,1)$, then $x\in\Bbb R$, and $x\notin\Bbb N$, so $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb N$. Thus, $(0,1)\subseteq\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb N$.

Comment: thanks! that makes sense i guess for some reason the (0,1) didnt register as not including 0 and 1 as an element contained.

Comment: @Jared: You’re welcome! I wondered if that might be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

No,no it means that $\mathbb R$ represents the set of real numbers and $\mathbb N$ represents the set of natural numbers. as usual, and your definition of subset is correct but i think you should remove $\mathbb N$ and only represent it using Real numbers.because it would include $0+\Delta(t)$,where $\Delta(t)$ represents really small, infinitesimal number. In decimals may be rational or irrational,which are both contained in real numbers. and you know my friend that $\mathbb N \subseteq [1,\infty)$,which can also be understood as a separate constraint for not taking natural numbers as our criteria.

hope you understand it!

Comment: you don't need to sign your answers.

Comment: I just change "nos" to "numbers, formatted a little bit, and corrected a small error :)